# update existing workbook using epplus C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus-4

I am trying to add new worksheet into existing workbook, code runs fine without any error. But changes are not being updated to the excel file.
Here is my code

```
string path = "C:\\TestFileSave\\ABC.xlsx";
FileInfo filePath = new FileInfo(path);
if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
    using(ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage()) 
    {
        using(stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) 
        {
            p.Load(stream);
            ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsName + wsNumber.ToString());
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = wsName;
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(184, 204, 228));
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            p.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The `stream` object is not tied to the `package`.  The only relationship is it copies its bytes in your call to `Load` afterwards they are separate.

You do not need to even use a `stream` - better to let the `package` handle it on its own like this:

```
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
if (fileinfo.Exists)
{
    using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
    {
        //using (stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            //p.Load(stream);
            ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsName + wsNumber.ToString());
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = wsName;
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(184, 204, 228));
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            p.Save();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here I have shown to write data into exiting excel file by creating a new sheet in same file. To answer your question: try using last two lines File.WriteAllBytes instead of p.Save().

```
string strfilepath = "C:\\Users\\m\\Desktop\\Employeedata.xlsx";           
using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(strfilepath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        p.Load(stream);
       //deleting worksheet if already present in excel file
        var wk = p.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Hola");
        if (wk != null) { p.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(wk); }

        p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hola");
        p.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToEnd("Hola");
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets[p.Workbook.Worksheets.Count];

        worksheet.InsertRow(5, 2);
        worksheet.Cells["A9"].LoadFromDataTable(dt1, true);
        // Inserting values in the 5th row
        worksheet.Cells["A5"].Value = "12010";
        worksheet.Cells["B5"].Value = "Drill";
        worksheet.Cells["C5"].Value = 20;
        worksheet.Cells["D5"].Value = 8;

        // Inserting values in the 6th row
        worksheet.Cells["A6"].Value = "12011";
        worksheet.Cells["B6"].Value = "Crowbar";
        worksheet.Cells["C6"].Value = 7;
        worksheet.Cells["D6"].Value = 23.48;                  
    }
    //p.Save() ;
    Byte[] bin = p.GetAsByteArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\m\Desktop\Employeedata.xlsx", bin);
}
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining your answer. Don't just throw in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I originally got the error code "A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT)) " from using this, but later learned that it was because the existing Excel file that I wanted to modify wasn't fully MS-Excel format compliant.  I created thee original excel file in Open office as an .xls file, but EPPlus was not able to read it. When I regenerated this original excel file in Online Excel, everything worked fine.